# JS, how can i refresh the page or div when json data changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

Hello i started javascript and im making a dynamic ajax GET page, (refreshes page when json data changed etc.).

My problem is i need to refresh page or container div when data is changed
this my code
HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="600">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="event"></div>
            <div id="counter">
        <span id="countdown"></span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "data.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json"

}).done(function (data) {
    var write = '<img src="' + data.img + '">';
    $("#event").html(write);
    $("#event").delay(data.countdown * 1000).fadeOut();
    var i = data.countdown;
    var fade_out = function () {
        $("#counter").fadeOut().empty();
        clearInterval(counter);
    };
    setTimeout(fade_out, data.countdown * 1000);
    function count() { $("#countdown").html(i--); }
    var counter = setInterval(function () { count(); }, 1000);
});
```

JSon is like this

```
{"img":"img\/maltolmeca.jpg","countdown":"60"}
```

Comment: i assume you're just trying to update the #event div with the data from the request, what gets output to the page when you run the above code?

Comment: @dyatesupnorth yep :P

Answer (score 0):

In this day and age, it might be worth you looking into libraries such as Angular, React and Vuejs which handle 'data refreshing' for you.

Anyway, in your `done()` function you can just call `location.reload()` which would refresh the page.

...though I imagine that isn't what you are actually trying to achieve. Refreshing the page like that is a bad user experience usually, so let's try a better solution.

One way of 'reloading' a div is to do something like this:

```
if (data.success){
    $("#event").fadeOut(800, function(){
      $("#event").html(msg).fadeIn().delay(2000);
   });
}
```

or even

```
$("#event").load("#event");
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put this code in to my php folder, its like from stone age but its ok for my project.

```
<script>
var previous = null;
var current = null;
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
        current = JSON.stringify(json);            
        if (previous && current && previous !== current) {
            console.log('refresh');
            location.reload();
        }
        previous = current;
    });                       
}, 2000);
```